# What does the ampersand mean in RFC 822's BNF rules?

Tags: bnf, rfc822, abnf

[The IETF RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) has these BNF rules:

```
text        =  <any CHAR, including bare         ; => atoms, specials,
                CR & bare LF, but NOT            ;  comments and
                including CRLF>                  ;  quoted-strings are
                                                 ;  NOT recognized.

qtext       =  <any CHAR excepting <">,          ; => may be folded
                "\" & CR, and including
                linear-white-space>

dtext       =  <any CHAR excluding "[",          ; => may be folded
                "]", "\" & CR, & including 
                linear-white-space>
```

I'd like to know what the ampersand symbol `&` signifies in these rules. The ampersand symbol is not defined by RFC 822's own Notational Conventions section (Section 2). I assume RFC 822 is using RFC 733 for its BNF/ABNF, but RFC 733 doesn't define what the ampersand means either.

From the context I've determined the ampersand **does not** mean any of the following:

- List item separator (that's what a comma is for, and the ampersand does not represent the final conjunction in an Oxford Comma-style expression because we see the `&` prior to the last `,` in the `text` rule).

  - And if it is a list-item separator, how should it be interpreted in the case of `dtext`?
- Concatenation (because a concatenation is described by having two adjacent production rules with no operator between them).

  - Additionally because `CRLF` is already a concatenation of CR and LF, but RFC 822 differentiates between `CRLF` and `bare CR & bare LF` in the `text` rule.

There's no mention of this in RFC 822's errata - and RFC's successor RFCs like 2822 replace the rules with ampersands with entirely new rules, so I can't infer what it means from the new syntax eithe.

So what does `&` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorthand English word "and". It even observes English punctuation rules.

Compare the 2 definitions from RFC 822:

```
     qtext       =  <any CHAR excepting <">,     ; => may be folded
                     "\" & CR, and including
                     linear-white-space>

     dtext       =  <any CHAR excluding "[",     ; => may be folded
                     "]", "\" & CR, & including
                     linear-white-space>
```

Comment: But why use "and" instead of a comma? Surely using `qtext = <any CHAR except <">, "\", CR, linear-white-space>` is better because it's entirely unambiguous.

Comment: The text between "<" and ">" is free form, and the author used it in an informal way to describe the syntax; It is just English prose, not to be consumed by a machine. and it is customary to use, informally, "&" as a shorthand for "and".

Comment: @BrancoMedeiros Right - I just think that punctuation symbols and prose shouldn't be used in technical grammar specifications because it leads to confusion like this :) - At least all the more recent RFCs I've read do use clear and unambiguous techniques to describe their grammars.